# How to fix the following issue with Chrome Driver and Chrome browser issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute basic script in Selenium Web Driver. The Chrome driver version is 80.0 and Chrome browser version is 80.0.

I'm able to see blank window after running the program and also I have read something like this:

> Enable protected mode please protect the ports used by chrome driver and related test framework to prevent access by malicious code

However I am unable to capture this message as it quickly display the error message as pasted below. How can I fix the issue?

My code:

```
package sanitytest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class chrometest {

public static void main(String[]args) {

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\rashm\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32)\\chromedriver.exe");
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

}
```

Issue :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 41468
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-41SP0FVR', ip: '192.168.0.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Comment: You should have a more specific title on your question.  Lots of people have trouble with their chrome driver with chrome.  We can't all open all of the "chrome driver with chrome" questions, just to figure out what the question is.

Comment: I seem to remember having trouble getting the actual version number out of one of these drivers.    No gui, no about box, no readme, no source.  So, no surprise, the v81 driver was labeled v80.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you are using the wrong version of chromedriver.

Your browser version might be 80+ but your chromedriver is 81+. That's the reason why your are getting this issue. Please download [chromedriver 80.0.3987.106](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/).

Here is the best approach that I can suggest. Using `WebDriverManager`, which will download the stable version of chromedriver based on the browser version.

**JAVA:**
If you are using maven, add the below to your pom.xml to load the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you code should be as shown below.

```
WebDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**PYTHON:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()
```

That's all, no need to download any drivers and setting up the paths. Webdriver take care of them.